# Script to organize folders

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, rename

I need to organize many folders, this folders must have some kind of format in their names. I need to rename them and put them like this:

```
parent folder 2nd name + "_" + 2 digits + "_" + folder name
```

This needs to happen with every folder where the .ps1 is executed.

Here are some better explanations, here we have some folders:

```
00_00_Master folder
+- 00_01_Activities
`- 00_02_Schedules
   +- 02_00_dir1
   `- 02_01_dir2
```

As you can see, the subfolders inside `00_02_Schedules` start with the *2nd "name"*.

Etc, with all folders (never files). Now for a better explanation, I added (it will happen a lot) 3 more folders inside 00_02_Schedules. It should be like this (before and after executing .ps1)

---

Before:

```
...
`- 00_02 Schedules
   +- 02_00_dir1
   +- 02_01_dir2
   +- dir3
   +- 12345dir4
   `- 01_01_dir5
```

After:

```
...
`- 00_02 Schedules
   +- 02_00_dir1
   +- 02_01_dir2
   +- 02_02_dir3
   +- 02_03_dir4
   `- 02_04_dir5
```

---

I will try to explain a little (I put all the code I had, even when I think some is useless now)

```
$var1 = 0
$var2 = 0
# It always has to work in the same place, never with a fixed path like
# C:\Users\etc\etc
$arr1 = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Directory 
$arr2 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
[string]$dir = Get-Location

$ruta = $dir | Split-Path -Leaf

# Did these 2 things because I needed the folder's name, I didn't know how 
# to do it better

# I think we can say this following code is useless now, I think I tried to do
# an array of arrays so I could cleave the name 

foreach ($Name in $arr1) {
    [void]$arr2.Add($Name)
}

foreach ($Directory in $arr1) {
    if ($Directory -match '^[0-9].*') {
        Rename-Item \$Directory -NewName { [string]($_.Name).Substring(5) } 

        # This is the part I've being having most problems with. I may say the
        # code works...as long a folder's name doesn't start with a number,
        # because it enters inside the loop and many error logs pops out. Also
        # it renames the folders previously renamed like 00_01_00_01, when it's
        # supposed to delete before rename them.

        # Also, I think it won't work if the numeric extension isn't equal to 5.
    }
}

$arr3 = $ruta -split '_'
$foldername = $arr3[1]
# Works, It splits and give me the second "piece" between the 2 "_"

foreach ($Directory in $arr1) {
    Rename-Item "$Directory" -NewName $("$foldername" + "_" + "$var1" + "$var2" + "_" + $Directory.Name)

    # I think it should have been: (I put it that way before) 
    # $("$foldername" + "_" + "$var2" + "$var1" + "_" + $Directory.Name)
    # but if I did that way, it renamed them like 10,20,30 instead of 01,02,03 etc.

    $var++

    if ($var1 = 9) {
        $var1 = 0
        $var2++
        # I suppose is not fancy, but in the result output I can see 2 numbers, not 1
    }
}
```

One more thing, is it possible to transform this (fixed) code to work in all folders in a recursive way? (would save a lot of work and executions).

Comment: Your information is ambiguous, once it's `00_02_Schedules` and then `00_02 Schedules` space separated? Also how should the second number be evaluated - first free number in the same level? Leading digits not complying with schema should be discarded? If it complies with the schema but the first number is wrong the s2cond already exists what to do then?

Comment: Sorry, I got edited several times and now for some error I can't edit again, but it's always with the _

Comment: Sorry, I got edited several times and now for some error I can't edit again, but it's always with the _

I think I understood what you are asking and I will try to reply:

If starts with a number, those numbers have to be deleted until the following character is not a non-numeric or "_". So if we have a subfolder inside 00_02_Schedules: 123_4folder1 will be first deleted to folder1 and then added the 02_00_folder1

The first "02" of the folder's name is because the 2nd name of the parent folder is "02". The "00" is a numeration inside that folder (00, 01, 02...) and "folder1" is the name

Comment: I brang the idea of "deleting and then renaming" because as you said, there may be duplicates or wrong schema's names. So I thought it would be better deleting all and then starts the enumeration without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this initial situation:

```
> tree
└───00_00_Master folder
    ├──00_01_Activities
    └──00_02_Schedules
       ├──01_01_dir5
       ├──02_00_dir1
       ├──02_01_dir2
       ├──12345dir4
       └──dir3
```

This script (adapt the Set-Location to fit your environment):

```
## Q:\Test\2017\08\18\SO_45750567.ps1
Function Test-DirSchema ($DirName) {
    # assume parent is already processed and complies with schema
    $ThisDir = GI $DirName
    # Get parent's second number for our first
    $First = $ThisDir.Parent.Name.Split('_')[1]
    If ($ThisDir.Name -Match "^$($First)_\d{2}_.*") {
        "{0} : {1} complies with schema" -f $First,$ThisDir.Name
    } else {
        $Highest = (gci "$($ThisDir.Parent)\$($First)_??_*"|Sort|Select -Last 1).Name
        $Second = [int]($Highest -Replace('^\d{2}_(\d{2})_.*','$1'))
        $Second = ($Second + 1).ToString('00')
        "{0} : {1} does not comply with schema" -F $First,$ThisDir.Name
        $NewName = "{0}_{1}_{2}" -F $First, $Second,$ThisDir.Name.TrimStart('0123456789_')
        "new: {0}" -F $NewName
        $ThisDir | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
    }
    "----"
}
Set-Location "A:\00_00_Master folder"

Get-ChildItem "[0-9][0-9]_*" -Rec |
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
        ForEach-Object {Test-DirSchema $_.FullName}
```

with this output:

```
>  Q:\Test\2017\08\18\SO_45750567.ps1
02 : 01_01_dir5 does not comply with schema
new: 02_02_dir5
----
02 : 02_00_dir1 complies with schema
----
02 : 02_01_dir2 complies with schema
----
02 : 12345dir4 does not comply with schema
new: 02_03_dir4
----
02 : dir3 does not comply with schema
new: 02_04_dir3
----
```

Will have this end situation:

```
> tree
└───00_00_Master folder
    ├──00_01_Activities
    └──00_02_Schedules
       ├──02_00_dir1
       ├──02_01_dir2
       ├──02_02_dir5
       ├──02_03_dir4
       └──02_04_dir3
```

The order is, due to different sorting, not exactly yours.
If there is no previous number it will start with `01`.

Comment: It's pretty good, but I tried creating copies of 00_01_dir1, 00_02_dir2 and 00_00_dir3 and it just keep going. There are 2 options: delete the ones are repeated (it should check them...it will go slow, I think) or it deletes the names and then orders them all. But you are in the lead, I will try to modify my code with yours and see if I can solve myself with that information (I don't think I will be able, but I will try).

If you can please use this information to improve your code as well, I will be very grateful

Comment: You should start in the `00_00_Master folder` otherwise there is no parent to get the number from.

Comment: While testing you could append a `-confirm` or `-whatif` to the ren command.

Comment: Does this code work in Powershell 2.0? (because I have no idea) It doesn't work on my laptop but it works on my desktop pc. I can't mix the 2 codes (I think) because of that. I tried to, before the if statement, delete every "xy_wz" so it always has to rewrite the folder's names

Comment: I just checked with powershell -version 2 switch and it works this way also. So I have no clue what's the matter with your laptop. Since my solution works (at least on your desktop) consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Yes, I was going to do that, sadly I don't understand why that happens, and the "mix the codes" thing does not work either. So the code will never delete, just add. Terrific job tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | ForEach { #Get All Directories
    $a = 0 #Reset Indexing to 01
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File | ForEach {
        $ParentFolderSecond = ($_.Directory.Parent.Name -split '_')[1] #Second part of folder's parent
        $Number = $a++ #Number incrementing by 1
        $FolderName = $_.Directory.Name #folder's name
        "$($ParentFolderSecond)_$($Number.ToString("00"))_$($FolderName)$($_.Extension)" #put this into a rename-item if it works OK.
    }
}
```

Does this match your specs?

it should work recursively as is but I think i'm missing something in the parent folder part.

it won't rename anything, just spit out a list of what the file names 'will' be.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {
    # find schedule directories below the current working directory
    $_.Name -match '^\d{2}_(\d{2})_Schedules$'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $prefix  = $matches[1]
    $pattern = "^${prefix}_(\d{2})_"

    # enumerate subfolders of schedule directory
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $_.DirectoryName -Directory

    # find highest existing index of folders that already conform to the
    # name schema
    $lastindex = $folders |
                 Where-Object { $_.Name -match $pattern } |
                 ForEach-Object { [int]$matches[1] } |
                 Sort-Object |
                 Select-Object -Last 1
    $nextindex = if ($lastindex) { $lastindex + 1 } else { 0 }

    # rename folders that don't conform to the name schema starting with the
    # index after the highest existing index (or 0 if there was none), remove
    # digits and underscores from beginning of folder name
    $folders | Where-Object {
        $_.Name -notmatch $pattern
    } | Rename-Item -NewName {
        $_.Name -replace '^\d(?:[_\d]*)', "${prefix}_${script:nextindex}_"
        ${script:nextindex}++
    }
}
```